# Fastest fish possible

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, hard-science, sea-creatures

I am trying to design the fastest pelagic fish that is mechanically possible. The fastest real life fish can swim up to 80 mph. What body design would allow a fish to swim significantly faster than 80 mph? How large will it be? What kind of fish? What would the fins look like?

I would like the fish to be able to swim as fast as mechanically possible, preferably at least 150 mph.

IT CAN NOT BE A SUPERCAVITATING MISSILE WITH A FISH PAINTED ON IT.

All evolutionary and metabolic constraints will be taken care of.

Comment: For reference, it takes a supercavitating torpedo to go 230mph and these are basically flying through an air bubble in the water. That works out to be a pressure of 991psi for a bullet shaped object an inch in diameter. So it would almost certainly need a nose even sharper and narrower than a swordfish's head or an airfoil-like head. And if it hits something, both things are obliterated. Then there is debris in the water. Not sure how it would navigate since it would need to see so far ahead to steer, if it could even steer at all.

Comment: The current top seed for fish is a hard limit from nature. Tuna and blue merlin get seriously hurt when they reach that speed, and cavitation prevents them from going faster.

Comment: Assume that all other problems are resolved, I am only interested in the mechanical function.

Comment: You'd probably an armoured head and something to stop the fins and scales from tearing off and some mechanism to reduce the heat from friction drag of the water. I'm not sure if the water could dissipate the heat from the friction. It might boil on top of cavitation. Not to mention how to actually propel throught the water that fast. I imagine any tail moving from side to side would be torn off. You'd almost have better luck as a squid in this respect.

Comment: Then how fast can a fish physically go and what would this theoretical fish be like.

Comment: The fastest non-cavitating torpedo is 86mph.

Comment: Nature is pretty efficient if they design something. Engineers are often looking at nature and not the other way around. The fish you've seen are probably already nearing the max in speed. I think all you can do is make them stronger in scales and muscles near magically (carbon nanotubing maybe?) and present that as the fastest.

Comment: This question as it now is ill phrased. If you remove all evolutionary and metabolic constraints then you are left with the only hard limit on velocity in nature: c.

Comment: I think we can calculate the oscillation of tail sweep and then factor in all the coefficients such drag, cavitation, density, undulating movement etc damn it I'm a pescetarian not a fish expert ;D

Comment: If the 80mph number is for sailfish, then recent studies suggest they don't go more than about 22 mph. (https://academic.oup.com/icb/article/55/4/719/634534) There is another study that estimates top speed at 33mph (https://bio.biologists.org/content/5/10/1415#xref-ref-21-1) but that's by analyzing the anatomy. They never observed this speed.

Comment: As an upper limit to underwater speed (without getting into things like supercavitation), consider that the fastest nuclear submarine could make 51 mph (82 km/hr), and had serious problems above 40 mph (64 km/hr) https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/26475/the-soviets-golden-fish-missile-submarine-still-holds-the-record-as-the-worlds-fastest

Comment: @Daron I was talking about the black marlin.

Comment: @Praearcturus Okay, I have checked those two papers for Black Marlin. One of them mentions the black marlin, but neither estimates its top speed. That said, they are a similar type of fish so I wouldn't be surprised if the early estimates (which are the same for both fish) for Black marlin were as far off as those for sailfish.

Answer (score 9):

**Supercavitating Missile with Fish Painted on the Side.**

[image]

Body design: Sleek metal cylinder with solid fuel rocket engine at the back and gas pump at the front. The pump ejects a bubble of gas through which the fish travels. This prevents cavitation damage.

Fins: Two stabilising fins at the back.

Top Speed: 230 mph

All evolutionary and metabolic constraints: Taken care of

---

Sarcasm aside, it's not obvious what type of answer you are looking for. There are several comments that point out how objects moving quickly though water suffer cavitation damage:

[image]

Cavitation is when the fluid gets churned up so small low-pressure bubbles are formed. The bubbles then collapse and damage whatever is nearby. [There is a well known predator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXK2G2AzMTU) that hunts this way. See also the [sexy version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wBYPjkGRdo).

If cavitation can make holes in a sleek metal propeller imagine what it can do to a living animal!

The question is tagged "hard science" so these comments are entirely appropriate. Ignoring problems like this makes the question no longer "hard science" and it's unclear where you draw the line for ignoring problems. In my answer I have ignored the problem "is actually a missile and not a fish".

Comment: Isn't it weird how the speed of sound acts as a speed barrier for aircraft. So you might assume that since water has a much faster speed of sound, you could go much faster before encountering such a barrier. But I guess due to the incompressible nature of water, cavitation pops up which limits your speed to be even less than what it was in air. Of course, that's ignoring the greater forces involved due to the higher density which is yet another limitation.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think there's some extra condition in there, like "speed caused by pressure differences cannot exceed the speed of sound". I remember that fact from a question about a monster throwing parts of itself into space. Does that ring any bells to you?

Comment: My completely unsupported, handwavey, reason why cavitation exists in water but not air is that water can evaporate while air cannot. So if you're talking about that gaseous water that might be where the speed of sound comes into play. But I'm not a mechanical engineer. I don't know about the "speed caused by pressure differences" thing. Kind of reminds me of the rocket equation when I hear that.

Comment: Sounds like a good reason for why air cavitation doesn't happen. The pressure differences of course does happen because that's how aircraft work, but they don't produce tiny little pressure difference bubbles.

Comment: @DKNguyen I mean there are certainly supersonic aircraft so the speed of sound isn't a hard barrier. Though it might be a hard barrier for travel without XX type of engine.

Comment: Well yeah, but its the first abrupt barrier.

Comment: The question is basically asking how fast a fish could mechanically go. If it can't travel at supercavitating speeds then how fast could a fish plausibly go?

Comment: @Praearcturus: That's an easy question: The fish could go juuuuust below supercavitating speeds.